# PostGis ST_Transform: failed to load NAD27-83 correction file (-38)

Tags: postgis, proj

So I'm getting some user drawn polygons in WKT with OpenLayers. (Web Mercator CRS) and I now need to now convert it to SRID4326 so can do some spatial queries. However, when it fails to do a ST_Transform. A simplified query I run that gives me the error:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
       ST_Transform('SRID=3857;POLYGON((-10179308.152034 5209576.5082574,-10140172.393558 4329021.9425348,-8516038.4167805 4329021.9425348,-9514000.2579329 5385687.421402,-10179308.152034 5209576.5082574))'::geometry,4326)
);
```

It gives me this error:

> ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (-1.08446e+07 5.1652e+06 0):
>   failed to load NAD27-83 correction file (-38)
>
> HINT:  PostGIS was
>   unable to transform the point because either no grid shift files were
>   found, or the point does not lie within the range for which the grid
>   shift is defined. Refer to the ST_Transform() section of the PostGIS
>   manual for details on how to configure PostGIS to alter this
>   behaviour. cohere=> select postgis_full_version();

Even after a bit of google-foo, I still can't figure out how to install the correction file I can do And I can do other transformations just fine (I tried 4326 to 2026 and 3857). I read somewhere to check to make sure PROJ is installed and it is:

`SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();`

> POSTGIS="1.5.2" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.6.26" USE_STATS

Thanks,

Comment: What operating system is it on? POSIX (Unix, MacOS X, etc.) or MS Windows? Do you know if you installed PROJ.4 yourself, or from packages?

Comment: @Mike Its on a RedHat 5.6 box. Now that you mention it, I don't remember explicitly installing Proj4 myself. It must have come from one of the many GIS tools I installed doing project research and maybe didn't come with the grid files I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build PROJ.4 from source, make sure to read the instructions, since you need to download the source AND the grid shift files separately. Furthermore, the grid shift files need to be unzipped in the correct directory before `./configure && make && make install`. They can't be installed after.

If you install PostgreSQL/PostGIS/GEOS/PROJ.4 from YUM packages, I highly recommend getting all of these from http://www.pgrpms.org/ since they are always current and up-to-date. To get started, I [wrote a guide for this on the postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation). With pgrmps.org, you should be able to find/install `proj-nad`, which is the grid shift data files (and it could already be automatically selected as a dependency, but I'm not sure). Similarly, Ubuntu has a `proj-data` apt package, which may (or not) be automatically selected as a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and this helped me http://www.mail-archive.com/postgis-users@postgis.refractions.net/msg12634.html

> Copying the directory \share\contrib\postgis\proj from the zip to
>   program files (C:\Program
>   Files\PostgreSQL\9.1alpha1\share\contrib\postgis\proj ) and restarting
>   postgres helped.

(but on Ubuntu)

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting postgres"?

Comment: I meant stopping and starting again postgresql server

Answer (score 3):

> SELECT
>   ST_AsEWKT(st_setsrid(ST_Transform(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-633510.090428,7506727.67383),900913),4269),4326),4326));

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you add a little explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: `yum install proj-epsg proj-nad`

Then restart postgresql